# exception thrown when running jar on Heroku

Tags: java, exception, heroku, jar

I followed this documentation [Using the Heroku Deploy CLI plugin](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-executable-jar-files#using-the-heroku-deploy-cli-plugin) to run my simple jar but when I execute this command :

```
jar main.jar --app myapp
```

This exception is thrown :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Not Found
    at com.heroku.sdk.deploy.utils.RestClient.handleResponse(RestClient.java:172)
    at com.heroku.sdk.deploy.utils.RestClient.get(RestClient.java:66)
    at com.heroku.sdk.deploy.ConfigVars.getConfigVars(ConfigVars.java:41)
    at com.heroku.sdk.deploy.ConfigVars.merge(ConfigVars.java:24)
    at com.heroku.sdk.deploy.Deployer.mergeConfigVars(Deployer.java:106)
    at com.heroku.sdk.deploy.Deployer.deploy(Deployer.java:68)
    at com.heroku.sdk.deploy.App.deploy(App.java:57)
    at com.heroku.sdk.deploy.App.deploy(App.java:61)
    at com.heroku.sdk.deploy.DeployJar.deploy(DeployJar.java:27)
    at com.heroku.sdk.deploy.DeployJar.main(DeployJar.java:105)
```

I've googled this exception but didn't found anything useful.
Note that this jar is running correctly in my computer without any exceptions.

Comment: What environment did you run cause error? What is the difference with you computer?

Comment: I run through my mac's terminal and after the excpetion I mentioned above heroku cli says  ▸    There was a problem deploying to APPNAME.
 ▸    Make sure you have permission to deploy by running: heroku apps:info      ---- but in my computer it works without any excepetions.

Comment: The error is because missing library. Did you check if this library available on you new environment?

Comment: How could I check this? aren't libraries packed in the jar?

Comment: I don't know if the lib is parked in jar or not. That is your jar. You can use `7zip` to open the jar and check it

Comment: I said that because the jar itself works locally.

Comment: Who knows if in local you have lib outside the jar? what is that jar include? You didn't provide a full description about the 2 environment. This error must be because missing the class of some libs

Comment: The jar even works in an isolated folder locally.Isn't that enough for saying that the lib is included in the jar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error usually means the app you are trying to deploy to does not exist (or you may not have access to it).

Double check that the app name is correct, and use the correct app name with the `-a` option in the command if necessary.